# Add Fragment to Activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, view, fragment

I'm trying to add some children to a parent `LinearLayout`. I searched some and found that these children need to be a `Fragment`.

My fragment: `faq_fragment.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/question_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:text="Title 1"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/answer_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:text="Description 1"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

My Activity: `new_activity.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:background="#0088ff"
    android:onClick="test">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

NewActivity.java:

```
public class NewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.new_activity);

        Map<String, String> info = new HashMap<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) info.put("Question " + i, "Answer " + i);

        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : info.entrySet()) {
            FAQFragment faq = new FAQFragment();
//          faq.titleLabel.setText(entry.getKey());
//          faq.descriptionLabel.setText(entry.getValue());

            FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.add(R.id.fragment_view, faq);
            ft.commit();
        }
    }
}

class FAQFragment extends Fragment {
//  TextView titleLabel, descriptionLabel;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
//      titleLabel = (TextView)container.findViewById(R.id.question_text);
//      descriptionLabel = (TextView)container.findViewById(R.id.answer_text);

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.faq_fragment, container);
    }
}
```

When I run it on my device the app crashes and gices me error message:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
```

Comment: try `return inflater.inflate(R.layout.faq_fragment, container,false);` in your `Fragment`

Comment: already asked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19301458/the-specified-child-already-has-a-parent-you-must-call-removeview-on-the-chil) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245131/the-specified-child-already-has-a-parent-you-must-call-removeview-on-the-chil)

Comment: @pRaNaY flag for duplicate then