# react-native-maps The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-maps

I have the following code:-

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { View, StyleSheet, ScrollView, Platform, Linking } from "react-native";
import Header from "../components/Header";
import PageTitle from "../components/PageTitle";
import PageSubTitle from "../components/PageSubTitle";
import SchoolIcon from "../components/svg/School";
import BottomLine from "../components/svg/BottomLine";
import Marker, { PROVIDER_GOOGLE } from "react-native-maps";
import PersonInfo from "../components/PersonInfo";
import VisitRow from "../components/VisitRow";
import Button from "../components/Button";
import { School as SchoolService } from "../services/School";
import Loading from "../components/Loading";
import MapView from "react-native-maps";

const School = ({ route, navigation }) => {
  const [region, setRegion] = useState({
    latitude: 29.3075287,
    longitude: 47.7105837,
  });

  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const [data, setData] = useState();
  useEffect(() => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    SchoolService.getSchoolById(route.params.schoolId)
      .then((r) => {
        console.log("schoolsss", r.data);
        setData(r.data);
        setIsLoading(false);
      })
      .catch((e) => console.log(e.response));
  }, [route.params.schoolId]);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Loading isLoading={isLoading} />
      <Header style={{ alignSelf: "center" }} />
      <ScrollView nestedScrollEnabled={true}>
        <View style={{ marginRight: 13, marginLeft: 13 }}>
          <SchoolIcon />
          <PageTitle>{data && data.name}</PageTitle>
          <BottomLine />

          <PageSubTitle>بيانات الأمناء:-</PageSubTitle>
          <PersonInfo name="محمد علي محمد" phoneNumber="50580600" />

          <PageSubTitle>آخر النماذج علي المدرسة:-</PageSubTitle>
          <ScrollView style={{ height: 120 }} nestedScrollEnabled={true}>
            {!isLoading &&
              data.forms.map((form) => {
                console.log("OneForm", form.user.civil_id);
                return (
                  <VisitRow
                    onPress={() => {
                      navigation.reset({
                        index: 0,
                        routes: [{ name: "Form", params: { id: form.id } }],
                      });
                    }}
                    date={form.created_at}
                    number={form.id}
                    visitor={form.user.first_name + " " + form.user.last_name}
                  />
                );
              })}
          </ScrollView>
          <Button
            style={{ marginLeft: "auto" }}
            onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Forms")}
          >
            عرض الكل
          </Button>

          <PageSubTitle>بيانات المدير:-</PageSubTitle>
          <PersonInfo name="محمد علي محمد" phoneNumber="50580600" />

          <MapView
            onLongPress={(loc) => {
              const scheme = Platform.select({
                ios: "maps://0,0?q=",
                android: "geo:0,0?q=",
              });
              const latLng = `${data.lat},${data.lon}`;
              const label = data.name;
              const url = Platform.select({
                ios: `${scheme}${label}@${latLng}`,
                android: `${scheme}${latLng}(${label})`,
              });

              Linking.openURL(url);
            }}
            showsUserLocation
            initialRegion={{
              latitude: 29.301712976361088,
              latitudeDelta: 0.21850550544601788,
              longitude: 48.03588207811117,
              longitudeDelta: 0.22801324725150351,
            }}
            provider={Platform.OS === "android" ? PROVIDER_GOOGLE : undefined}
            style={{
              height: 100,
              width: "100%",
              marginTop: 4,
              alignSelf: "center",
              marginBottom: 80,
            }}
            //onRegionChange={(r) => console.log(r)}
          >
            {data && data.lat && (
              <Marker
                coordinate={{ latitude: data.lat, longitude: data.lon }}
                pinColor="red"
              />
            )}
          </MapView>
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    </View>
  );
};
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
  },
});
export default School;
```

When i view the page in Android using expo go i am getting this error:-
[image]

Depedencies:-

```
"dependencies": {
     "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.3.0",
"@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.13",
"@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.1",
"add": "^2.0.6",
"axios": "^1.4.0",
"expo": "~48.0.15",
"expo-env-info": "^1.0.5",
"expo-image-picker": "^14.1.1",
"expo-secure-store": "^12.1.1",
"expo-splash-screen": "~0.18.2",
"expo-status-bar": "~1.4.4",
"expo-updates": "~0.16.4",
"react": "18.2.0",
"react-content-loader": "^6.2.1",
"react-hook-form": "^7.43.9",
"react-native": "0.71.8",
"react-native-document-scanner-plugin": "^0.7.3",
"react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.9.0",
"react-native-google-places-autocomplete": "^2.5.1",
"react-native-loading-spinner-overlay": "^3.0.1",
"react-native-maps": "1.3.2",
"react-native-permissions": "^3.8.0",
"react-native-radio-buttons-group": "^3.0.0",
"react-native-reanimated": "~2.14.4",
"react-native-rtl-layout": "^0.0.1",
"react-native-safe-area-context": "4.5.0",
"react-native-screens": "~3.20.0",
"react-native-select-dropdown": "^3.3.3",
"react-native-svg": "13.4.0",
"yarn": "^1.22.19"
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245131/the-specified-child-already-has-a-parent-you-must-call-removeview-on-the-chil). Also see [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: @KenWhite no dear, i am working under expo project i cannot customized android native files